# jquery append element and keep reference for removing it later

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, scope

what is the correct method to append a div to dom, and keep a handle for manipulating that dom later ? and case removing it will the refrence be deleted also ? if not how can i ?

this is an example code of what i came out with, please let me know your opinon and if there is a better more solid method for doing this.

note that i keep reference in an array because many elements can manipulate element.

```
var layovers=[];

function ajaxMe($e){
//do some ajax call
var lay=layoverThis($e);

layovers[lay].remove(); //does this remove added element from dom ? does it unset layouvers[lay] too ?
}

function layoverThis($e){
        var p=layover.push($('<div class="overlay" ><span><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"/>loading</span></div>')) - 1;
        $e.append(layover[p]);
        return p;
    }
```

nearest example i can think of is like opening a folder in windows Os.

when you open a folder: a new window opens to your desktop, while also there is a taskbar tab that is added linked to same window that was appended to your desktop, allowing system to manipulate window (close-restore minimize etc..), so how do i do this in javasript.

my question is how to make such behavior in a manner that is flexible and not hacky or memory wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a psudoClass and an index - add the event to the delete element as you create the element in the DOM. OR have an onclick that removes the parent div that was appended..

So, you're code will look like:

```
 function layoverThis($e){
    var p=layover.push($('<div class="overlay" ><span><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-    spin"/>loading</span> <span class="closeThis" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();" > Close </span></div>')) - 1;
    $e.append(layover[p]);
    return p;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you, i have a number of other solutions.

Update:

To facilitate the object to be selectable, I would use a psudoClass..

```
document.ready(function() {
    addADiv($('#myParent')); 

    getArrayOfDivs().css('background-color', 'red'); 

    doAjax(lastClicked);
});

function doAjax(ctrl)
{

}

var lastClicked = "";
$('.dynamicDivs').click(function() {
    lastClicked = $(this);
});

function getArrayOfDivs() {
   return $('.dynamicDivs');
}

function addADiv($where){
    var uniqueIdentifier = $('.dynamicDivs').count() + 1;
     $where.append($('<div class="overlay dynamicDivs ' + uniqueIdentifier + ' " ><span><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-     spin"/>loading</span></div>'));

}
```

Comment: well this is nice option to allow user to remove element, yet i'm searching for more flexiable solution that would also allow me to handle this dom using js.

Comment: Hi Momen, Are you still having difficulty? Is this solution going to work for you or would you like a more comprehensive solution using ID's/etc? I removed the array.push/etc as you can just select on the psudo class entered and get an array of the elements still within the DOM. its much handier than actually trying to keep track of what is there vs what is removed.

Comment: well, my question i was actually seeking an objective opinion on best practice to accomplish this, your approach is nice, yet hacky, refrenceing last clicked can go crazy along with searching class indetifier which might for crazy reason collision in future with other elements.

Comment: I agree 100% - To be honest I would definitly prefer the onclick elements, or adding events as they are dynamically assigned to the dom directly.. Its just difficult to see the complexity of what you are trying to do from the information available.. but yes this solution would be for something very very basic.